# How to disable certain days in a month in a Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date

I am trying to use bootstrap date picker for picking date in one of my forms and I am able to generate the date picker with the below code. Now I have a condition that only dates ranging from 1st to 25th of every month should be enabled and the remaining 5 or 6 dates should be in disabled mode. I got to know how to disable weekdays and specific dates from googling but unable to understand how to enable a date range for every month.

Below is the code I am trying

```
$('#slide_date').datepicker({
format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
todayBtn: "linked",
clearBtn: true,
autoclose: true,
todayHighlight: true
});
```

Comment: take a look at `setStartDate` and `setEndDate`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do that in Bootstrap Datepicker. But you CAN do this in Jquery UI datepicker. Try the following tested code.

Please make sure you have reference to `JqueryUI.js` and `JqueryUI.css`

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="slide_date" />
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(function(){
    $("#slide_date").datepicker(
        {
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        //getDate() returns the day (0-31)
        if (date.getDate() == 25 || date.getDate() == 26 || date.getDate() == 27 || date.getDate() == 28 || date.getDate() == 29 ||date.getDate() == 30 ||date.getDate() == 31 ) {
            return [false, ''];
        }
        return [true, ''];
        }
        }

    );
});
```